# AJAX periodical polling data after submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

this question might duplicate but I need some help to fix the code.

Scenario: Once the submit button is clicked, ajax will send the form data to server . And based on the form data (variables and update-speed), perform polling to get the response data.

Current bottleneck: Since the speed and variables is declared globally, the correct response will show only first time the submit is clicked and completed. Otherwise for the setTimeout polling for doPoll, it will show null value since the form data is not captured.

Desired Outcome: Once user submit the click button, pull the data periodically based on user'update speed value and save all the response in key-value array. The response will used to draw Chart.js.

Any suggestion and thanks.

Code:

```
    $('#submit-button').click(function(e){

        var speed = $('#update-speed-input').val();
        var variables = $('#variables-select-input').val();

      function doPoll(speed,variables){
            $.post("{{ route('getFilterUnitData') }}", {
             speed: speed,
             variables: variables,
          }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                setTimeout(doPoll,speed);
            });
        }

      $.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('getFilterUnitData') }}",
          method: 'post',
          data: {
             speed: speed,
             variables: variables
          }
          ,
          success: function(response){
             console.log(count(response));
          },
          error: function(result) { 
                console.log(result);
            },
            complete: setTimeout(doPoll(speed,variables), speed) 

      });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning the values to "window" object? like to window.speed and window.variables

The speed and variables is inside a function scope and not global.